# throttled response from IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Let's say I have a URL on my site, `http://foo.com/RobotTrap`. This isn't a real page, but robots keep trying to crawl it for some reason.

How can I make it so that IIS throttles the response to this one request? Suppose I want to return the string `"Silly robot, there is nothing here for you 10110110"`, one byte every 5 seconds.

Also I want to do this without tying up an asp.net worker thread. Is this even possible?

Comment: If it isn't a real page then don't they get 404? Why need a custom response? Your site should be able to handle bots in that basic capacity. They'll do a lot worse then hitting a non-existant page. Bing continues to hit my most query intensive page every .01s.

Comment: So your response to unwanted connections is to keep the connections open as long as possible?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev they do get a 404, but they keep trying over and over. we are not talking about a well behaved robot here.

Comment: @dan yeah that happens... even the nice ones aren't nice.

Comment: @trideceth12 yep. the hope is they notice and either they fix their script or stop.